Custom notification sound in Flutter
So I want to allow the users to set their own notification sounds like in WhatsApp in both Android and iOS. Is there any package which allows us to do that
I looked into flutter_local_notifications but could not find any solutions.

You can try Onesignal for the custom sound notification i have implemented in one of my application.

You need to add the audio file in the raw folder for Android in mp3  format and on iOS, you need a .aiff format sound.
But this has to be added in the application folder beforehand and can not changed during runtime this is done from OS and there is no alternative.
Documentation for custom notification sound:
https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/49c487f351185c8067d0378ea896cc0fc24b4fa9/flutter_local_notifications/example/lib/main.dart#L426
Search on YouTube for full details on how to add files and clear steps
